# Fitting cumulative gaussan distribution

Tags: python, montecarlo, mle, cdf

I try to reproduce the data analysis of [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John-Franchak/publication/334140833_Development_of_affordance_perception_and_recalibration_in_children_and_adults/links/5f21a838299bf134048febd1/Development-of-affordance-perception-and-recalibration-in-children-and-adults.pdf) scientific paper but I struggle to understand the methodology as I'm novice with stats.

[image]

Here's what he says he does:

- Cumulative Gaussian functions were fit to decision data with Maximum likelihood
  fits for the threshold. Parametric bootstraps with 1000 Monte Carlo iterations determined 95% confidence intervals for threshold parameters.

Here I reproduce his data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
plt.style.use(['science','notebook'])

x = np.array([12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32])
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.33, 1, 1])

plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='none', marker='o')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

I have not found a way to apply an MLE to a CPD and I don't understand the order in which he applied the MLE and MC methods. Did he first derive the CPD to a PDF and then apply MLE and MC?

Comment: You could ask authors about methodology

Comment: The paper says they used the [Palamedes toolbox](http://www.palamedestoolbox.org/) so that might be a good place to start.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Yes, I did but I don't know if I will get an answer.

Comment: @myrtlecat I have looked at the toolbox as well as the book, by the way I am still trying to figure it out but not having a background in both mathematics and matlab makes it a bit complicated.